# How to Create Custom Link Line between two nodes JavaScript Use GoJs API

Tags: javascript, gojs

GoJs has object Link [default link arrow head form GoJs API] http://gojs.net/latest/samples/arrowheads.html

but now I want to create custom Link for complete Family Tree Diagram
And all link must flexible

[Emotional relation link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26aia.png)

how can I design my link form GoJs API

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this interesting question.

You can do this in the next version of GoJS.  Take a look at this new sample that comes in version 1.6: http://gojs.net/beta/samples/relationships.html.  As that sample demonstrates, if you look at the source code for that sample, you can define your own custom renderings.

[image: Custom link renderings in GoJS]

The four at the bottom of this screenshot also demonstrate how a **Link** can have more than one **Shape**, each of which can have a custom rendering.